# Why do I have to statically link a c program if I want to use it as the init program for the kernel?

Tags: init

I'm learning about how Linux works and for that I'm watching [Tutorial: Building the Simplest Possible Linux System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sk9TatW9ino&t=2406&ab_channel=TheLinuxFoundation) by Rob Landley. He basically goes through some steps to build a minimal system and around [20:00](https://youtu.be/Sk9TatW9ino?t=1200) he starts explaining about building a *"hello world binary"* that he will later use as the init program for the kernel to run as the very first program.

My question is, why do I have to statically link the hello.c application I want to use as the init application for the kernel to run after booting (as mentioned at [21:39](https://youtu.be/Sk9TatW9ino?t=1299) and seen at [23:05](https://youtu.be/Sk9TatW9ino?t=1385))?

Comment: You do? `systemd` seems to be dynamically linked: `sudo file -L /proc/1/exe` => 
`/proc/1/exe: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked ...`

Comment: The init program can be anything that the internal kernel code which backs the execve system call can run. It can be a shell script, or a python script. The advantage of it being a statically linked binary is that it has less dependencies, so you don't need to have the run time linker present and libraries it wants to link to. So you might need something like /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 in your initial filesystem as well as the init program itself.

Comment: Notice he doesn't say you **have** to statically compile it, he just says that **he** will statically compile it. As previous comments said, it might be better in some cases to eliminate dependencies. For instance, if some of the libraries are located in separate filesystem than the root filesystem. The init process is responsible for mounting all the filesystems (from `fstab`), so you could see how this becomes a problem.

Comment: @icarus I think this is the correct answer, could you convert this comment into an answer to accept it. I say this because he mentions something along these lines later in the video.

Comment: How old is this video series? This restriction was in effect long, long ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The init program can be anything that the internal kernel code which backs the execve system call can run.

Many systems use a shell script, but it could even be a python script.

The advantage of the init program being a statically linked binary is that it has less dependencies, so you don't require to have the run time linker  and the shared libraries that it links to present.

On a 64 bit x86 system you might need something like /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 in your initial filesystem as well as the init program itself.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, why do I have to statically build the hello.c application I want to use as the init application for the kernel to run after booting (as mentioned at 21:39 and seen at 23:05)?

There's no such requirement for the vanilla Linux kernel. It will happily load an init program along with its shared dependencies:

```
$ ls -la /sbin/init
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Nov 15 13:21 /sbin/init -> ../lib/systemd/systemd

$ ldd `which /sbin/init`
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcd31ee000)
    libsystemd-shared-249.so => /usr/lib/systemd/libsystemd-shared-249.so (0x00007fd28d983000)
    libseccomp.so.2 => /lib64/libseccomp.so.2 (0x00007fd28d950000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fd28d925000)
    libmount.so.1 => /lib64/libmount.so.1 (0x00007fd28d8e0000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib64/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fd28d8ce000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /lib64/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fd28d8a0000)
    libkmod.so.2 => /lib64/libkmod.so.2 (0x00007fd28d883000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd28d868000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd28d65e000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00007fd28d653000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib64/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007fd28d61b000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib64/libcap.so.2 (0x00007fd28d611000)
    libcrypt.so.2 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.2 (0x00007fd28d5d5000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib64/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fd28d499000)
    libip4tc.so.2 => /lib64/libip4tc.so.2 (0x00007fd28d48f000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib64/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fd28d46b000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fd28d17d000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /lib64/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007fd28d04b000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib64/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007fd28cf73000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fd28cf47000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd28de62000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fd28ceb0000)
    libeconf.so.0 => /lib64/libeconf.so.0 (0x00007fd28cea5000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd28cdc9000)
    libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib64/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007fd28cdbe000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd28cda4000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007fd28cd9c000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib64/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fd28cd76000)
    libpcap.so.1 => /lib64/libpcap.so.1 (0x00007fd28cd29000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib64/libffi.so.6 (0x00007fd28cd1c000)
    libibverbs.so.1 => /lib64/libibverbs.so.1 (0x00007fd28ccfa000)
    libnl-route-3.so.200 => /lib64/libnl-route-3.so.200 (0x00007fd28cc74000)
    libnl-3.so.200 => /lib64/libnl-3.so.200 (0x00007fd28cc50000)
```

Comment: ...Unless some of the libraries required by init are located on a **different filesystem** than the root filesystem.

Comment: @aviro I believe this is (partly) why there is no longer support for `/usr` as a separate filesystem

Comment: @roima, I'm pretty sure that /usr can be installed on a separate filesystem. And anyway most of the dependencies are on /lib64. Maybe you mean other folder?

Comment: @aviro, there are some that seem to think a separate `/usr` isn't or shouldn't be supported: https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/ https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/ https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge